# Batch-Rename heterogeneous file extensions to one extension

Tags: windows, cmd, batch-processing

I have multiple files each with a different extension in a folder. I need to rename all of them to one extension (.txt).

[image]

I have tried with the following command:

```
ren *.* "%fname%:~0,-3%.txt"
```

But I receive the following error:

```
A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.
```

In short I need to convert all files in a folder of miscellaneous types to one type(.txt)

Please help.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.*" ' ) DO (
 SET "filename=%%a"
 SET "filename=!filename:.=!.txt"
 ECHO(REN "%sourcedir%\%%a" "!filename!"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

If your renaming scheme had worked, appears to want to remove the last 3 characters of the name, then add `.txt`

This would still yield duplicate filenames:

> core.13848ab -> core.1384.txt
>
> core.13848ac -> core.1384.txt

In the absence of a clear explanation of the scheme you are aiming for, the code above will remove any `.` from the name and add `.txt`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked as desired. Can you explain me what does filename=!filename:.=!.txt do?

Comment: Assign to filename (the contents of filename, replacing the string between the `:` and `=` by the string after the `=`) It's within `!` instead of `%` because `!` returns the changed value of the variable within the loop (in delayedexpansion mode) whereas `%` returns the initial value (when the command was encountered.) The string between `:` and `=` is `.`, and there is no string after `=`, so it replaces all `.` characters with *nothing*; iow, removes all dots within the variable `filename`. To that, simply add `.txt`